# Android XXHDPI resources

Tags: android, android-resources

The Google Nexus 10 comes out shortly, and is [the first device to use `xxhdpi` resources](https://plus.google.com/113735310430199015092/posts/Ne8teAxeH45). It sports a display density of about 300 DPI (according to [the Nexus 10 website](http://www.google.com/nexus/10/) and [this calculator](http://members.ping.de/~sven/dpi.html)).

However, when I go to the Android documentation, it states:

- `ldpi` : ~120dpi
- `mdpi` : ~160dpi
- `hdpi` : ~240dpi
- `xhdpi` : ~320dpi
- `xxhdpi` is not specified.

How come the Nexus 10's 300 DPI screen is `xxhdpi` instead of `xhdpi`, and what *should be* the approximate DPI of `xxhdpi`? Should we even worry about having new resources (aside from icons) for `xxhdpi` at this point, or should we just let the OS scale up `xhdpi` resources?

Comment: The nexus 10 has 300 PPI (PIXELS PER INCH), which is different to DIP/DP (DENSITY INDEPENDANT PIXEL) which is a display metric invented by Android.

To complete the confusion, DPI (DOTS PER INCH) is basically the same as PPI (PIXELS PER INCH), but do not confuse it with DIP (DENSITY INDEPENDANT PIXEL).

DPI != DIP

Comment: yeah @user1234813 they all obviously different, but the panorama is not as terrible as you paint it. If you know what the acronyms mean, it's nearly trivial!

Answer (score 110, accepted):

According to the post linked in the G+ resource:

> The gorgeous screen on the Nexus 10 falls into the XHDPI density
>   bucket.  On tablets, Launcher uses icons from one density bucket up
>   [0] to render them slightly larger.  To ensure that your launcher icon
>   (arguably your apps most important asset) is crisp you need to add a
>   144*144px icon in the drawable-xxhdpi or drawable-480dpi folder.

So it looks like the xxhdpi is set for 480dpi.  According to that, tablets use the assets from one dpi bucket higher than the one they're in for the launcher.  The Nexus 10 being in bucket xhdpi will pull the launcher icon from the xxhdpi.

[Source](https://plus.google.com/118292708268361843293/posts/ePQya3KsTjW)

Also, was not aware that tablets take resources from the asset bucket above their level.  Noted.

Comment: That seems conflicting to me. Roman Nurik's post says "Support for XXHDPI for Nexus 10 launcher icons"... the post you quoted says that the Nexus 10 is "XHDPI", but also says that "[T]o ensure that [it] is crisp you need to [use] the drawable-xxhdpi ... folder". **Edit:** Interesting, one of the comments (from Roman) says, "+Benjamin Weiss remember, the display itself isn't xxhdpi, it's just where the launcher/system will be looking for one-bucket-up icons." You may want to add this to your post.

Comment: I kind of sort of did.  They say that the tablets take resources from the assets of the higher dpi than the one they're in.  I'll put that more clearly in the answer.

Comment: Made a tool for myself after reading this post, it might be usefull for someone else: http://android-dpi-converter.warting.se/

Comment: 2013 update on this one: As of Android 4.4 Google-experience launcher and the Nexus 5, you'll need a one-bucket-up icon for the launcher on phones, not just tablets. That means you'll need an xxxhdpi icon for the Nexus 5 launcher to render at full crispness; see https://plus.google.com/+RomanNurik/posts/EURexV9yF32 . That may sound like a joke, but it isn't: 640dpi assets for launcher icons are now a requirement; xxhdpi ones will just gets scaled up fuzzily in a bad way (since it's to an in-between resolution used by the launcher, not an even multiple).

Answer (score 8):

The DPI of the screen of the Nexus 10 is ±300, which is in the unofficial [`xhdpi` range of 280‑400](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range).

Usually, devices use resources designed for their density. But there are exceptions, and exceptions might be added in the future.
The Nexus 10 uses `xxhdpi` resources when it comes to launcher icons.

The standard quantised DPI for [xxhdpi is 480](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#DENSITY_XXHIGH) (which means screens with a DPI somewhere in the range of 400‑560 are probably xxhdpi).

Comment: Look sky, You down vote my answer for same reason. Thing has been change from the time when question had asked. So posting a new answer is not a harm and its not a reason to down vote at all !!

Comment: Seriously, someone call Wil Wheaton.

Answer (score 8):

xxhdpi was not specified before but now new devices S4, HTC one are surely comes inside xxhdpi .These device dpi are around 440. I do not know exact limit for xxhdpi  See [how to develop android application for xxhdpi device Samsung S4](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2013/03/how-to-develop-android-application-for.html)
I know this is late answer but as thing had change since the question asked

**Note**  Google Nexus 10  need to add a 144*144px icon in the drawable-xxhdpi or drawable-480dpi folder.

Answer (score 7):

480 dpi is the standard QUANTIZED resolution for **xxhdpi**, it can vary something less (i.e.: 440 dpi) or more (i.e.: 520 dpi). Scale factor: 3x (3 * mdpi).

Now there's a higher resolution, **xxxhdpi** (640 dpi). Scale factor 4x (4 * mdpi).

Here's the [source reference](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/07/25/xxxhdpi-spotted-in-4-3-source-prepare-your-eyeballs-for-android-in-4k-resolution/).

Comment: Do you have any sources for that?

Comment: Do you mean a reference page on android developer, such as [Supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)?

Comment: Yes, it's what I meant. But your reference page is not showing the resolutions `xxhdpi` and `xxxhdpi` (at least it does not seem to be documented, yet). Do you have any reference for `xxhdpi` and `xxxhdpi`resolutions (scaling factor and dpi)?

Comment: Look at this [page](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/07/25/xxxhdpi-spotted-in-4-3-source-prepare-your-eyeballs-for-android-in-4k-resolution/)

Comment: Nice, you should add this page to your answer :)

Comment: OK... doing it now. Thanks for pointing it out. Should cite sources.

Comment: @statosdotcom Thank YOU, for eventually subscribing... ;)

Comment: @statosdotcom Now, simply put... generative music on a modular is really "programming in hardware" (by plugging cables and turning knobs, acting on switches, ...) with unpredictable (but somehow controlled) results. The synth then makes music for you, indefinetely "evolving" it over time. I'm building my hardware synth. And meanwhile (will take years to buy every module, cable, and little bits), using a free software one. It is so addictive and not much different from programming a software. Only that in hardware you can't "save". The best you can do is shooting a photo and/or draw a schema.

Answer (score 3):

The resolution is 480 dpi, the launcher icon is 144*144px all is scaled 3x respect to mdpi (so called "base", "baseline" or "normal") sizes.

Answer (score 0):

The newer android  phones in the market like HTC one, Xperia Z etc have resolutions in the >480dpi range, putting them in the new xxhdpi class as well. The new assets might be useful for them too.

Answer (score 0):

A set of four generalized sizes: small, normal, large, and xlarge
Note: Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), these size groups are deprecated in favor of a new technique for managing screen sizes based on the available screen width. If you're developing for Android 3.2 and greater, see Declaring Tablet Layouts for Android 3.2 for more information.

A set of six generalized densities:

ldpi (low) ~120dpi

mdpi (medium) ~160dpi

hdpi (high) ~240dpi

xhdpi (extra-high) ~320dpi

xxhdpi (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi

xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high) ~640dpi

From developer.android.com : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

As per this [PPI calculation tool](https://pixelsperinchcalc.com/), Google Nexus 10 has a display density of about 300 DPI...

However, Android documentation states that:

ldpi : ~120dpi
mdpi : ~160dpi
hdpi : ~240dpi
xhdpi : ~320dpi
xxhdpi is not specified.

I think we just let Android OS scale up xhdpi resources...