# Need to differentiate with 10 inch tabs of different resolutions

Tags: android, resolution, tablet

I have a requirement in android to support my app in different tablets like google nexus 10 and samsung galxy 10 inch tablet. Nexus 10 is double the resolution of samsung 10 inch tab. I need to place different images for nexus 10 to make my app looks with better clarity for nexus 10 . But both the devices are taking the image from the drawable-xlarge. How can I differentiate between these two devices in drawable level and layout level. Same case is applicable for phones as well where I need to differentiate Samsung galaxy s4 which is double the resolution of xhdpi phones.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

Comment: Use the new `xxhdpi` qualifier - (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13215587/android-xxhdpi-resources)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-xlarge` is a screen **size** qualifier. Your drawable folders should use screen **density** qualifiers (`-mdpi`, `-hdpi`, `-xhdpi`, `-xxhdpi`). If you must, you can use both, e.g `-xlarge-hdpi`

Comment: xlarge-hdpi is differentiating the google nexus 10 with other normal 10 inch tabs. It works fine. I hope for s4 similarly xxhdpi will work. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget the new [smallest width qualifiers](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseSWQuali). They are of a great help when you need to differentiate based on screen resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't consider a non-Nexus [tablet](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004YIFP04) anymore, based on how bad manufacturers have been at bothering to update them. The Nexus devices being "Official Google" devices and getting updates from Google means that they're going to be updated for a long while going forward, and once that ends, you can still unlock and root them through a defined process & update things yourself if you care to do so.

I can't think of any 10" Android tablet I'd have other than the Nexus 10. They're really that good.