# "No resources match the configuration" when selecting different layouts

Tags: android

I'm currently working on a tablet layout for my app, and up until now everything has been working fine. However, when I load up my layout now, and select a tablet-sized configuration from the drop-down list (Nexus 10 or 10.1 WXGA), I'm met with the following error:

No resources match the configuration

```
    , , Locale Language ___Region __, , sw800dp, w1280dp, h800dp, Extra Large Screen, Short screen aspect ratio, Landscape Orientation, Normal, Day time, X-High Density, Finger-based touchscreen, Soft keyboard, No keyboard, Hidden navigation, No navigation, Screen resolution 2560x1600, API Level 17

Change the configuration or create:

res/layout-sw800dp-w1280dp-h800dp-xlarge-notlong-land-notnight-xhdpi-finger-keyssoft-nokeys-navhidden-nonav-2560x1600-v17/newtabletlayout.xml
```

This is surely some form of error, as I'm using nothing but the standard Nexus 10 configuration, any ideas why it won't display?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the required layout file is not available for the configuration you have selected . Are you providing the default layout file in layout folders ? Can you give us the list of drawable and layout folders you are using in the project ?

Comment: Sure: drawable, drawable-hdpi, drawable-large

Comment: Can you also list layout folders you are using ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13215587/android-xxhdpi-resources - refer this link for more info