# Difficulty in xhdpi screen resolution

Tags: android

eg:- Samsung Galaxy S III (1280 x 720) and Samsung Galaxy S 4 (1920 x 1080) uses resources from xhdpi. I'm hvaing 3 icons in a row aligned left, centre and right with size of (256 x 256) but it gets overlapped on SIII and on s4 their is a wide gap between icons.

What should be the size of icon to fit it as 1/3 of screen's width or is there any workaround to do so?

here is sample snapshot of layout after following mentioned solutions.
http://postimg.org/image/97aabr2wd/

its getting scaled properly but leaves space on top and bottom. I want result similar to snapshot in this image http://postimg.org/image/r6ico4vil/

where 1, 2 and 3 should be of same height. Its just a space after 3 consecutive red, green and blue images. how to achieve this? thanks in advance.

Comment: better way is give size(layout_width, height) of imageview in layout. it will never overlap..

Answer (score 1):

The samsung Galaxy S4 is XXHDPI, and not XHDPI.

Here is a way to check for the device density :

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
int density = dm.densityDpi;
switch(density)
{
 case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
  Toast.makeText(context, "ldpi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  break;
 case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
  Toast.makeText(context, "mdpi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  break;
 case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
  Toast.makeText(context, "hdpi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  break;
 case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
  Toast.makeText(context, "xhdpi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  break;
 case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH:
  Toast.makeText(context, "xxhdpi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  break;
}
```

I took if from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18994661/1940676).

About having 3 images filling the whole screen width you can use a linear layout with layout weight.

```
 <LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="9" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="3" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="3" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="3" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I've got s 4 is xhdpi info from this http://blog.blundell-apps.com/list-of-android-devices-with-pixel-density-buckets/

Comment: allright then is there any device with 1080 width and categorized as xhdpi

Comment: @kevz see my edit, and run that code on the galaxy s4

Comment: A tablet could do that. For example the nexus 10. it's got even more that 1080 and it's XHdpi

Comment: okey tnx for code. I have set images height and width to wrap_content and I don't want them to scale just want them to fit without any gap in between. what should I do to achieve this?

Comment: can you post your xml layout?

Comment: @user1940676 I've done same thing with my layout. but I've st width to wrap content. so that it won't get scaled.

Comment: @user1940676 I'm having portrait view only

Comment: @user1940676 I've checked ur layout file and it work g8

Answer (score 0):

In android-

px = dp * (dpi / 160)

1.So in your first question 960dp x 720dp at 320dpi means 1920px x 1440px for xlarge screen in landscape mode using above formula.

2.640dp x 480dp at 240dpi means 960px x 720px for large screen in landscape mode.

[enter link description here](https://blogs.captechconsulting.com/blog/steven-byle/understanding-density-independence-android)

Answer (score 0):

You can't guaranty a 1/3 of the screen with just an image.  even if two devices have the same dpi (or XHdpi) it doesn't mean they have the same size.
The only way to do that is with code or in the layout xml.
Try use wights.

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="0.33"
```

with this code you guaranty that the view will be a 1/3 of the screen if width.

Comment: tnx for ur answer it helped me