# Android ic_action_search.png in XXHDPI is too small (96px)

Tags: android, user-interface, icons

I am using [Android action bar icon pack](http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html) for my app. The **ic_action_search** icon (magnifier) is too small and I have seen on another website that the action bar icons size should be as follows:

```
Mdpi 48x48
Hdpi 72x72
Xdpi 96x96
Xxdpi 144x144
```

But in the Android action bar icon pack it is:

```
Mdpi 32x32
Hdpi 48x48
Xhdpi 64x64
Xxdpi 96x96
```

Has anyone had the same problem? Do you have the 144x144 versions of those icons? I would rather avoid having to do a dirty resize in photoshop...

Thanks!

Edit: I am using an Action Bar for this, and here is the XML file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <!-- Search Widget -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          android:showAsAction="always"
          android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"/>

    <!--  Settings will never display -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

</menu>
```

Illustration is here:

[image]

Comment: If you need to have one in that size have you tried to resize your `Button` or `ImageView` in `layout_width/heigh` to `144px`?

Comment: see my edit, I am using an ActionBar without changing any property

Comment: Maybe you can try to change your `Theme`. What's yours?

Comment: Holo Light, I dont see why it would be linked to the theme, since I am loading the pictures mysef

Comment: I tested your code and my `ic_action_search` is bigger than yours, it's like the first image. I have the latest version of `Android Studio` , try to update it. Perhaps you won't have the same problem

Comment: Looks like https://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html is telling us that AB icons should indeed be 32 dp, BUT for *phones* it tells -- and your AB is probably not 40-48 dp high (as it would be on a phone), but rather 56 dp (the standard value for the tablet). Now, I've heard (seems we are all using rumors, not docs, thanks to Google) that tablets are supposed to use icons (at least launcher icons) from one bucket up: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13215729/110118. And that must be it.