# XXHDPI and XXXHDPI dimensions in dp for images and icons in android

Tags: android, screen-size, image-size

I have been able to get dimensions for the following :

A set of six generalized densities:

- ldpi (low) ~120dpi
- mdpi (medium) ~160dpi
- hdpi (high) ~240dpi
- xhdpi (extra-high) ~320dpi
- xxhdpi (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi
- xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high) ~640dpi

These are the dimensions :

- xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
- large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
- normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
- small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

But what should be the ideal dimensions for images and icon sizes with device like XXLarge and XXXlarge screens.

Comment: possible duplicate of [about android image size and assets sizes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581649/about-android-image-size-and-assets-sizes)

Comment: Expecting answer in dp for XXLarge and XXXLarge screens like the others mentioned above

Comment: xxhdpi 1920×1200 px - Nexus 7 tablet - 7 inches Sony Z3 Tablet Compact LG G Pad 8.3 - 8.3 inches Sony Xperia Z2 Tablet - 10.1 inches

Comment: xxxhdpi 2560×1600 px - Nexus 10 tablet - 10.1 inches ~Google Nexus 9 Sony Xperia Z4 tablet Samsung Galaxy Note Pro 12.2 Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 Samsung Galaxy Tab S 10.5 Dell Venue 8 7840

Answer (score 1):

try like this. hope it works

```
drawable-sw720dp-xxhdpi and values-sw720dp-xxhdpi

drawable-sw720dp-xxxhdpi and values-sw720dp-xxxhdpi
```

link might destroy so pasted ans

**reference** [Android xxx-hdpi real devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21452353/android-xxx-hdpi-real-devices)

**xxxhdpi was only introduced because of the way that launcher icons are scaled on the nexus 5's launcher Because the nexus 5's default launcher uses bigger icons, xxxhdpi was introduced so that icons would still look good on the nexus 5's launcher.**

also check these links

[Different resolution support android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706076/font-size-and-images-for-different-device/16910589#16910589)

[Application Skeleton to support multiple screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242111/application-skeleton-to-support-multiple-screen)

[Is there a list of screen resolutions for all Android based phones and tablets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587854/is-there-a-list-of-screen-resolutions-for-all-android-based-phones-and-tablets)

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21452353/android-xxx-hdpi-real-devices check editted ans..

Comment: Android docs on that you don't need xxxhdpi size: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#xxxhdpi-note

Answer (score 0):

it is different for different icons.(eg, diff sizes for action bar icons, laucnher icons, etc.) please follow this link [icons handbook](http://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/chart/android/) to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a vector. Instead of worry about different screen sizes you only need to create an .svg file and import it to your project using [Vector Asset Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html).