# Screen density for xx-hdpi screens

Tags: android, screen

In the Android documentation, it is said that the resolution for ldpi screens is approximately 120dpi, 160 for mdpi, 240 for hdpi and 320 for xhdpi. But what about xxhdpi?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13215587/android-xxhdpi-resources

Comment: Please look at the docs for `DisplayMetrics` at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#DENSITY_XXHIGH

Comment: xxhdpi: 480 dpi. xxxhdpi: 640 dpi